# Blinking 3 led's in parallel?

Tags: led, parallel, blink

I have a PIC development board which has few on board led's. I am programming MCU so that it can blink 3 led's in a parallel manner. I have made the following code:

```
void led1() //blink led1 with delay of 700ms
{
  LED1 = 1;
  Delayms(700); 
  LED1 = 0;
  Delayms(700);
}
void led2() //blink led2 with delay of 1200ms
{
  LED2 = 1;
  Delayms(1200);
  LED2 = 0;
  Delayms(1200);
}
void led3()  //blink led3 with delay of 2000ms
{
  LED3 = 1;
  Delayms(2000);
  LED3 = 0;
  Delayms(2000);
}

void main()
{
  //******//
  /** code to blink led's in parallel **/
  //*****//
}
```

What logic should I write to blink led's in paralledl manner. I know embedded can only do one task at a time but there has to some coding solution for it. I don't want to use FreeRTOS for simple applications. I want them to blink at the same time. Like 1st one blinking with the delay of 700ms, at the same time, 2nd blinking with delay of 1200ms and at the same time 3rd blinking with delay of 2secs. All 3 parallely

Comment: Something like: 1) Switch all LEDs on, 2) Delay, 3) Switch all LEDs off, 4) Delay, 5) Goto 1.

Comment: No  I want them to blink at the same time. Like 1st one blinking with the delay of 700ms, at the same time, 2nd blinking with delay of 1200ms and at the same time 3rd blinking with delay of 2secs. All 3 parallely

Comment: @user46573544 you need to  use inbuilt timer not delay function

Answer (score 1):

Create a say 1 or 10 or 100 mS counter.
For each LED provide a count down register.
Each time the timer "ticks" decrement each LED count down register.
When a register reaches zero, process the LEd and reset the timer.
QED.

You can also use count up to a limit or other schemes. The key point is that each task is essentially independent with the single timer source driving them.

---

```
LEDRED = 7  
LEDGREEN = 12  
LEDBLUE = 20  

DO Until_hell_freezes_over

DELAY 100 mS

Decrement LEDRED  
IF LEDRED = 0  
    Toggle RED_LED  
    LEDRED = 7  
ENDIF  

Decrement LEDGREEN  
IF LEDGREEN = 0  
    Toggle GREEN_LED  
    LEDGREEN = 12  
ENDIF    

Decrement LEDBLUE   
IF LEDBLUE = 0  
    Toggle BLUE_LED   
    LEDBLUE = 20   
ENDIF   

LOOP
```

Comment: @CZAbhinav Read the pseudo code above. Self explanatory with a little effort. Follow what happens when it runs.

Comment: @user46573544 Please consider reading and rereading the pseudo code  until you understand it - the code essentially IS comments in this case. CZAbhinave would also benefit from following through the code by eye to  see what happens. When the timers LEDRED, LEDGREEN and LEDBLIUE are non zero the if statements do not evaluate to true and the code loops ~= every 100 mS. After 7 loops LEDRED decrements to zero and the RED LED is toggled. ASND the timer / cpunter LEDRED is reset to 7 to produce another 7 x 100 ms = 700 ms count down. ....

Comment: Meanwhile green and vlue keep counting down until they too reach zero, toggle their LEDs, reset their timers and proceed. ...

Answer (score 0):

I would make a timer that goes off every 100ms. Then call a function 'update_led_x' that will increment a counter for that led. When it gets to a certain count, it toggles the led and resets the count.

Comment: See Russel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rewrite the code such that the turning on and off of all three LEDs can happen independently rather than in sequence. If you want accuracy, then a timer interrupt will be a good idea. Otherwise, and if this is the only thing you want the code to do, then you could have a while(1) loop withe a single delay of the minimum you need followed by a handler function for each of the LEDs. Each LED will need its own counter which keeps being reset to the value of the required number of these minimum delays and the three LED handlers will test, increment and reset the respective counters each time round the loop.As the counters reach half their value, the LED would turn off and as the counter is reset to 0 they would turn on.